# How do I get Facebook page username or facebook page ID from url

Tags: php, facebook, url, extract, facebook-page

I've made a website where users can submit their Facebook page and I orginally coded it assuming that they would of set up a vanity URL for their page. E.g.

> http://www.facebook.com/**myfacebookpage**

But I forgot that some pages can have urls such as

> http://www.facebook.com/pages/myfacebookpage/**54878424154545487**

My question is how do I use PHP to grab the part of the url in **bold**?

Thanks!

Comment: find the very last slash and take the rest of the string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this:

```
$url='http://www.facebook.com/pages/myfacebookpage/54878424154545487'; // the input
$pieces = explode('/', $url); // divides the string in pieces where '/' is found
$key=end($pieces); //takes the last piece
```

Answer (score 7):

You can just recode your application to use `https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=`

Which will take both

- http://www.facebook.com/myfacebookpage and
- http://www.facebook.com/pages/myfacebookpage/54878424154545487

Examples

- https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=https://www.facebook.com/boo
- https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=https://www.facebook.com/pages/phwd/113702895386410