# How to get Facebook Page ID from Page URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, asp-classic, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token, facebook-authentication

I need to get the Page ID from the Page URL.  This is NOT from inside a page tab, that's easy.  This is similar to what is being done here: http://findmyfbid.com

Any help would be appreciated as I have been searching for over an hour!  Bonus points for showing how to do this in classic ASP.  I have no issue getting signed requests & parsing them, the URL to ID portion is what is throwing me.

thanks :)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/url

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884295/how-do-i-get-facebook-page-username-or-facebook-page-id-from-url

Comment: The second link does not give you the ID.  The first one is what I was looking at initially, I just cannot seem to get it to work - it always responds with "[object]" when I call the api code in Javascript.  With the example above, there are no prompts, etc.  It's seamless - does anyone have a full working code example of the above functioning?  thx

Answer (score 2):

As noted above in 1st answer commments, that does work, but it's not the data that we want since it's an external url.  THIS is the correct way to do it:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/**cocacola**?access_token=[yourtoken]

OR

This works too:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/**https://www.facebook.com/cocacola**?access_token=[yourtoken]

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do it:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/url

if you are using a GET request, be sure to append `access_token=appid|appsecret` to the URL you are requesting and it will work.

Thanks for the tip to point me in the correct direction Alex!

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. :( This gives the EXTERNAL url ID for the URL, not the page id.  There has to be another way to get the actual page URL form the graph.